# What is the impact of Software Architecture on Requirement Analysis?

Tags: design, architecture, requirements, sdlc

> Write the impact of software architecture on Requirement Analysis

I was given the above question in my assignment. I have studied about Software Architecture and Requirement Analysis but I'm still confused by it.

Does **Software Architecture** have any impact on **Requirement Analysis**?

I have gone through my teacher's lecture and I couldn't find anything notable regarding this matter. He has also said that we have to do our own research on this.

According to my research **Requirement Analysis** is done before any prototyping or architecture designing. Which means Software Architecture isn't involved in the Requirement Analysis process. So how is it even possible to describe Software Architecture's impact on Requirement Analysis?

Comment: What does your textbook say about this?  What did your teacher say about it in his lectures?

Comment: I don't recall any of his lecture mentioning this particular thing. I also go through his several slides too but couldn't found anything reliable regarding that...
I think it's given for self study I guess.

Comment: Then it sounds like the professor wants you to think about it.  Here's some food for thought: in a perfect world there would be no correlation between requirements and architecture.  Software exists to fulfill requirements; the requirements don't care how that is accomplished.  Nevertheless, there are always real-world constraints, and they always affect every aspect of the SDLC.  Processes don't exist in a vacuum.

Comment: So, how can I relate Requirements with Software Architecture? 
A small example might be perfect in this case...
Because I am all out of thoughts on this one...
So that I can answer that question in both directions on whether it does have any impact or doesn't have.

Comment: A simple example: If you're writing a business application, you probably aren't going to use a game engine.

Comment: I guess it will do the perfect job for me...
Appreciate it... @RobertHarvey

Comment: @RobertHarvey: one part of the business of where I work is 3D visualization of things like buildings - one architectural option discussed was to use Unity (ok, this is surely not the kind of business you had in mind ;-)

Comment: Ergo the word "probably."

Comment: @AbdulRafayAliKhan: the question sounds strange to me - sure it was not "what's the impact of the SDLC on Software Architecture"? Was it really the other way round?

Comment: @DocBrown Well the question in my assignment and in this post are the same... So I'm pretty sure that's the same question...
But believe me I had the same thought in my mind when I first saw the question, so I confirmed it from my teacher and he says the question still remains the same you and have to put your thinking on it...

Comment: Well, to have a software architecture which can have an impact, there should exist a software with that architecture, for example a platform on which you are going to develop something. So maybe the question was meant "what impact does the platform's architecture have to the SDLCs phases"?

Comment: So it's like if we decide to rework on an existing system which already have a defined architecture? @DocBrown

Comment: @AbdulRafayAliKhan: maybe, I don't know, just guessing. You were the one participating in your teacher's lectures, I can only give you some ideas of where to look for.

Comment: I guess the explanations here, all made it easier for me to understand in both the ways... So it's a win condition for me... But still I have to log argue with my teacher on that and let's see what he has to say about it... I'll surely write it down here what he says...  @DocBrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, requirements analysis should be done before anyone has thought about a solution. Thus architecture should have no impact on it. In the real world however things may be different. If your company has standardized on some platform you will usually have to work within that environment and that given architecture will be a constraint to what can be required. But the correct answer to this question in an educational setting would probably be "none".

Comment: Also can you please throw some light on the other phases too?
It would be really helpful...
And I can have a more clear view on them too...
@martin